# Does C++'s std::regex have an equivalent to Python's re.MULTILINE?

Tags: c++, regex

I want to use `^` and `$` to match strings at the beginning and end of lines, respectively. For example:

```
std::string multiline = "fifth\nsixth\nseventh\neighth\nninth";
std::cout << regex_search(multiline, std::regex("^s")) << endl;
```

prints `0`. In Python one could use `re.compile('^s', re.MULTILINE)`; is there a good way to do this in C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, this is an issue with the specification, as described in [LWG issue 2343](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-active.html#2343).

In summary, there is currently no portable way to enable multiline mode in C++ regex.

> **2343. Is the value of the ECMA-262 RegExp object's multiline property really false?**
>
> In the following "Multiline" is the value of the ECMA-262 RegExp object's multiline property.
>
> In ECMA-262, there are some definitions that relate to `Multiline`:
>
> - ECMA-262 15.10.2.6:
>
>   - If `Multiline` is true, `^` matches just after `LineTerminator`.
>   - If `Multiline` is false, `^` does not match just after `LineTerminator`.
>   - If `Multiline` is true, `$` matches just before `LineTerminator`.
>   - If `Multiline` is false, `$` does not match just before `LineTerminator`.
> - ECMA-262 15.10.4.1, 15.10.7.4:
>
>   - By default, `Multiline` is `false`.
>
> So, the C++11 standard says that `Multiline` is `false`. As it is `false`, `^` matches only the beginning of the string, and `$` matches only the end of the string.
>
> However, two flags are defined in 28.5.2 [re.matchflag] Table 139:
>
> - `match_not_bol`: the character `^` in the regular expression shall not match [first,first).
> - `match_not_eol`: the character `$` in the regular expression shall not match [last,last).
>
> As `Multiline` is false, the `match_not_bol` and the `match_not_eol` are meaningless because they only make `^` and `$` match none.
>
> In my opinion, `Multiline` should be `true`.
>
> FYI, `Multiline` of the existing implementations are as follows:
>
> `Multiline=false`:
>
> - libstdc++ r206594
> - libc++ r199174
>
> `Multiline=true`:
>
> - Visual Studio Express 2013
> - boost 1.55

Read more about the [Modified ECMAScript regular expression grammar](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/ecmascript) on cppreference.

Comment: Do any of the other grammars have a multiline option? I've been playing around with them for a while but I can't get them to work. For example, `echo "first[newline that won't show up when I post this]
second" | grep "^s"` on a command line produces `second`, but `regex_search(multiline, std::regex("^s", std::regex::grep))` returns false.

Comment: @EMBLEM: Checking the documentation of BRE and ERE, there doesn't seem to be any multiline option. Other flavors (except for ECMAScript) are mostly based on BRE and ERE, so their behavior shouldn't differ. Chances are that you have to tokenize the input string into separate lines and apply the regex.